# MySQL: Sum and Substract TOGETHER in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Could you help me with a select please?

I have two demo tables:

TabA:

```
ID  year    Company
1   2018    FGG
2   2018    FGG
3   2020    FGG
4   2020    FGG
5   2018    AV
6   2018    FGG
7   2018    FGG
8   2020    FGG
9   2020    FGG
10  2018    AV
```

AND

TabB:

```
ID  DT  Quantity
1   01  1
2   01  2
3   01  3
4   01  4
5   01  5
6   02  1
7   02  7
8   02  8
9   02  9
10  02  10
```

I need this result:

```
**year  Company DT  Quantity**  
**2018  FGG 01  3**   (1+2) as sum for 2018 group by company, DT
**2020  FGG 01  4**  (3+4) - (1+2) as (sum for 2020) – (sum for 2018) group by company, DT
**2018  AV  01  5**   5  as sum for 2018 group by company, DT
**2018  FGG 02  8**  (1+7) as sum for 2018 group by company, DT
**2020  FGG 02  9**  (8+9) - (1+7) as (sum for 2020) – (sum for 2018) group by company, DT
**2018  AV  02  10**    10  as sum for 2018 group by company, DT
```

I tried this one:

```
SELECT 
A.year,A.company,B.DT,
CASE
WHEN A.year='2020' AND A.company='FGG' THEN
((SELECT sum(quantity) FROM TabA A join TabB B
ON A.id=B.id where A.year='2020' AND A.company='FGG')
- (SELECT sum(quantity) FROM TabA A join TabB B
ON A.id=B.id where A.year='2018' AND A.company='FGG'))
Else sum(quantity) END quantity
from TabA A
join TabB B ON A.id=B.id
group by 
A.year,A.company,B.DT order by DT, year;
```

But this is not correct. Although the amount for 2018 is ok for every DT and every Company but the quantity for 2020 is 13 for both DT (instead of 4 for DT '01' and 9 for DT '02'), so this substract is not group by DT  '01' and '02' separately .

Please help me with correct solution.

Comment: What if a company only has data in 2020?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are running MySQL 8.0, you could use aggregation and window function for this:

```
select
    a.year,
    a.company,
    b.dt,
    case 
        when a.year = 2018 
            then sum(b.quantity)
        when a.year = 2020
            then sum(b.quantity) 
                - sum(case when a.year = 2018 then sum(b.quantity) else 0 end) 
                  over(partition by a.company, b.dt)
    end quantity
from taba a
inner join tabb b on b.id = a.id
group by
    a.year,
    a.company,
    b.dt
```

You did not *exactly* asked for what follows, but: we can make this a little shorter and more generic by just substracting the previous aggregate quantity (or 0 if there is none):

```
select
    a.year,
    a.company,
    b.dt,
    sum(b.quantity) - coalesce(
        lag(sum(b.quantity)) over(partition by a.company, b.dt order by a.year), 
        0
    ) quantity
from taba a
inner join tabb b on b.id = a.id
group by
    a.year,
    a.company,
    b.dt
```

Comment: Thank you very much GMB! God bless you. It works :) I tried the first (with 2020 instead od 2000) and it s perfect.

Comment: Do you know please if it s possible to rewrite this select in any other manner? Your script is correct, I tried to run it on MariaDB too (an older version 5.5.60) and it seems there is a problem with clause over(partition by..) Could you maybe recommend me something other please, this time for MariaDB?